# Best way to represent a stockroom

Tags: optimization, storage, logistics

I'm currently working on a project where I try to optimize the way objects are assigned a spot in a stockroom. Where we want the most frequently bought products as close to the front as possible, with a decreasing order towards the back. I was thinking of somehow representing this using an array, where array[x] = 0 represents a wall, array[x] = 1 represents a path where one could walk, and array[x] = Object represents some item in a shelf. With properties such as distance from drop off point, etc.

Any one have any tips or things I should think about?

Comment: Hey DKT - please check out this meta post - [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823). Your question as-is is very broad - trying to solve it yourself, then coming back around with 1. what you've tried and 2. what specifically you're stuck on, would greatly increase your chances of getting useful answers :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't yet meet the suggested [How to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) standards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.